# Three.js | GLTF Rubik Cube 3D Rotation Problem

Tags: three.js, rotation, gltf

Im trying to create a rubik cube but i keep having problems with rotations, when is a single face rotation everythinks looks fine but when i combine 2 rotations it get weird

One Rotation 90 degrees on the left face - Rotation on the x axis

[image]

[image]

After second rotation on the back face with 45 degrees - rotation on the Z axis

[image]

[image]

I also found out if i do the X axis rotation it appears that i have to do Y axis rotation on some cubes and Z axis rotation on another for all to work good but that solution doesnt work.

I created a group consisted of the frame of the cube and the faces.
Loads everything then if it is Last, adds the group to the scene.
The this.cube is an array of groups.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code. Paste the code. This is not just a recommendation